# DisplayMember in Combobox not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this method that adds `Conta` instances to a `ComboBox` called "comboContas":

```
public void AdicionaConta(Conta novaConta)
{
    comboContas.Items.Add(novaConta);
    comboContas.DisplayMember = "Titular";
}
```

Note that I've set the `DisplayMember` property to "Titular". Here is my `Conta` class:

```
public abstract class Conta
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public double Saldo { get; set; }

    public Cliente Titular { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "titular: " + this.Titular.Nome;
    }       
}
```

Now, "Titular" is of `Cliente` type. 
Here's `Cliente` class:

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }

    public Cliente(string nome)
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ToString do Cliente: " + this.Nome;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to show in the "comboContas" ComboBox is something like "ToString do Cliente: Gabriel".
However, the `ToString` method of the `Cliente` class is not being called. Instead, the one being called is from the `Conta` class.

[image]

This is pretty simple stuff and I really don't know what's happening. If I change `DisplayMember` to any other property, it works. If I change the type of the "Titular" property to any other type, the `ToString()` of this other type is called. It just doesn't work with `Cliente`.

Comment: If you want to do this the correct way then you bind the combobox to a `BindingList<Conta>`. Then you manipulate the underlying source and not the internal collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is wrong with your code (setting it after every add instead of in advance?) because it indeed works as expected. Check it out:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Conta
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public double Saldo { get; set; }
        public Cliente Titular { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "titular: " + this.Titular.Nome;
        }
    }
    public class Cliente
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Rg { get; set; }
        public Cliente(string nome)
        {
            this.Nome = nome;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ToString do Cliente: " + this.Nome;
        }
    }
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form { Padding = new Padding(16) };
            var comboBox = new ComboBox { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Parent = form };
            comboBox.DisplayMember = "Titular";
            comboBox.Items.AddRange( new []
            {
                new Conta { Titular = new Cliente("Victor") },
                new Conta { Titular = new Cliente("Mauricio") },
                new Conta { Titular = new Cliente("csni") },
            });
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure why what you are doing isn't working, but one way that would likely work is to do something like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public string DisplayName { get { return "ToString do Client: " + this.Nome; } }
}
```

Then, just change your combo box to bind the DisplayMember to DisplayName:

```
public void AdicionaConta(Conta novaConta)
{
    comboContas.Items.Add(novaConta);
    comboContas.DisplayMember = "Titular.DisplayName";
}
```

I hope this helps!